# How to make work wkhtmltopdf library in Odoo v11

Tags: python, odoo

I am facing this issue while taking pdf report in odoo11, I following possibilities but it doesn't works for me. Help me fix this issue.

```
sudo apt-get purge wkhtmltopdf
```

Then try using the commands below:

```
cd /tmp/

sudo wget http://download.gna.org/…/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd…
```

then install the package using dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb

sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
```

[image: error while print invoicing ledger report]

Comment: Try to do the cps like this: sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf and sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage

Comment: When you start the server, it shows you some lines specifying where is the wkhtmltopdf library, something like this: `2018-02-07 16:04:23,744 12822 INFO ? odoo.addons.report.models.report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Answer (score 2):

you can download directly from odoo nighlty 
https://nightly.odoo.com/extra/

or try the below codes in your terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wkhtmltopdf

sudo apt-get remove --purge wkhtmltox

sudo apt-get install xvfb libfontconfig wkhtmltopdf

sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then restart odoo server and refresh the browser. Try to print report again.